# How to configure pom.xml for integrating all dependent libs in install4j installer using maven

Tags: java, maven, install4j

I try to use install4j with Maven 3 but I didn't understand how to configure Maven und install4j to integrate all dependent libraries in the install4j installer.

Our goal is to integrate the install4j install builder with our build server. 
But I didn't understand how the install4j project file will get the information about the dependent libraries which have to be integrated in the installers but will be resolved by MAVEN.

Has anybody an idea how to set up install4j and Maven pom.xml to solve our issue? It would be gret if anybody can point me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect all your dependencies with the `maven-dependency-plugin` in some folder like `${project.build.directory}/installer-dependencies` and than add the directory at the screen `Installer -> Tab Custom Code & Resources` in your install4j-configuration. During the maven build install4j will collect all jar files from this directory and put these to the installer medium. We are using install4j with maven this way for four projects now and it works like a charm :).

Answer (score 0):

The maven plugin for install4j does not assemble structural information from the POM, it just executes the install4j build. All the information about the installer and the files that should be distributed is already contained in the install4j project file.